# inserting date in to mysql but current date is stored

Tags: php, android

I have an Android app and I write a web services using PHP and my database is MYSQL database. There is a form in android to collect the information about uses and save it into the database using my php service.

**filed_name : entry_date
type: varchar(50)**

the entry_date is user can enter from UI. whenever i insert data into database the entry date value is today's date.

if i run the php alone with default value it will work correctly. when i run from app its not enter correct date.

```
$entry_date = $_REQUEST['entry_date'];
if(isset($entry_date))
{
    $x = explode("-", $entry_date);
    $entry_date = $x[2]."-".$x[1]."-".$x[0];
    $entry_date = strtotime($entry_date);
    $entry_date = date('Y-m-d', $entry_date);
}
```

in android , i pass like this

```
values.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entry_date", entry_date_text));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use strtotime() http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

```
// You don't need to contain a array element into variable
// $entry_date = $_REQUEST['entry_date'];
if(isset($_REQUEST['entry_date'])) {
    $entry_date = strtotime( $_REQUEST['entry_date] );
}
```

Comment: I believe you have a mistake somewhere :

[root@voip02nl ~]# php -a
Interactive shell

php > echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("12-6-2017") );
2017-06-12

also make sure you the date format is in standard YYYY-MM-DD :

php > echo date("Y-M-d", strtotime("2017-05-12") );
2017-May-12

Answer (score 0):

Use like this, this is working for me

```
<?php
    $entry_date = "10-05-2017";
    if(isset($entry_date))
    {
        $x = explode("-", $entry_date);
        $entry_date = $x[2]."-".$x[1]."-".$x[0];
        $entry_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($entry_date));
        echo $entry_date;
    }
?>
```

Comment: its not working bro, it will save like 17-06-2017 but i pass the date like 12 replace of 17 but no luck

Comment: @teddycherrykj check it here `//phpfiddle.org/lite?code=<?php\n$entry_date = "10-05-2017";\nif(isset($entry_date))\n{\n $x = explode("-", $entry_date);\n $entry_date = $x[2]."-".$x[1]."-".$x[0];\n $entry_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($entry_date));\n echo $entry_date;\n}\n?>\n`

Comment: i already denote that if i run php file alone it will give correct output but when i run using app its not insert correct date

Comment: @teddycherrykj check what you are getting here

Comment: yes i checked its working but when i test with same editor with my code also working but in live it does not work